# requests.get() not crawling entire common crawl records for a given warc path

Tags: python-requests, common-crawl, warc

i have implemented https://dmorgan.info/posts/common-crawl-python/ as described in this link. However, I want to crawl entire data rather than partial data unlike as described in this post. So, in this code chunk,

```
def get_partial_warc_file(url, num_bytes=1024 * 10):
with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
    buf = StringIO(r.raw.read(num_bytes))
return warc.WARCFile(fileobj=buf, compress=True)
```

I have made the following change:

```
def get_partial_warc_file(url):
with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
    buf = StringIO(r.raw.data)
return warc.WARCFile(fileobj=buf, compress=True)
```

This code chunk increases the number of records for a given warc path but it does not crawl entire number of records. I can't find a possible reason for the same. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It could be caused by [bug #21 of the warc module](https://github.com/internetarchive/warc/issues/21).

Comment: Hi, I think that in this blog piece, the warc.gz file is being streamed. We are not reading a downloaded warc.gz file. Is there a work around for that?

Comment: Or does any latest version of warc solve this issue?

Comment: Gzip can read a stream: https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html

Comment: Work-around: wrap the stream into a gzip.GzipFile (as suggested by Mark) or a [gzipstream](https://github.com/commoncrawl/gzipstream) as in [cc-mrjob](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-mrjob). The warc module then gets the decompressed stream.
Replacement: [warcio](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/warcio) is actively maintained, see [cc-pyspark](https://github.com/commoncrawl/cc-pyspark) as example how to use it.